# ng-messages default error message

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have ng-messages + ng-message display a default error message?

For instance:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="number" name="number" min="10" max="100" required ng-model="number" />
</form>
<div ng-messages="myForm.number.$error">
  <div ng-message="required">Number is required</div>
  <div ng-message>There's something wrong with number!</div>
</div>
```

I would like "There's something wrong with number!" to show up if there's any error *besides* required.

Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure about a general solution, but most errors on numbers fall under the `$error.number` property.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="number" name="number" min="10" max="100" required ng-model="number" />
</form>
<div ng-show="myForm.number.$error">
  <div ng-show="myForm.number.$error.required">Number is required</div>
  <div ng-show="!myForm.number.$error.required && myForm.number.$error" >There's something wrong with number!</div>
</div>
```

Plnkr Demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aIJ1W8qTGiKHLJYJg0fe?p=preview

Comment: This technically works, but is not very maintainable if you had more errors states you wanted to show.

Comment: yeah i would agree on that..even I am looking how to accomplish the same when have more error states

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a directive that accomplishes a lot of the boiler plate stuff for validations. It includes allowing for a default message:

```
angular.module('validations').directive('showErrors', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^form',
      link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var data = el.data();
        var inputName = el.attr('name');
        if (!inputName)
          return;

        var baseFormName = ngModelCtrl.$name;
        var baseFieldName = baseFormName + '.' + inputName + '.$error.';

        var validationMessages = '';
        var validators = {};

        var defaultValidationConditions = [];
        var defaultValidationMessage = '';

        angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
          if (key.indexOf('se') === 0 && key[2] === key[2].toUpperCase()) {
            var validationProperty = key.substring(2).toLowerCase();

            // if this is the default message, just grab it and keep looping.
            if (validationProperty === 'default') {
              defaultValidationMessage = value;
              return;
            }

            var condition = baseFieldName + validationProperty;

            if (!validators[value]) {
              validators[value] = [];
            }
            validators[value].push(condition);

            // if we have a message for this error, we want to exclude it from the default
            defaultValidationConditions.push('!' + condition);
          }
        });

        defaultValidationConditions.push([baseFormName, '.', inputName, '.$invalid'].join(''));

        angular.forEach(validators, function (conditions, message) {
          var conditionString = conditions.join(' || ');

          validationMessages += '<label ng-show="' + conditionString + '" class="error">' + message + '</label>';
        });

        // if a default validation message was specified, we need to create a label
        if (defaultValidationMessage) {
          validationMessages += '<label ng-show="' + defaultValidationConditions.join(' && ') + '" class="error">' + defaultValidationMessage + '</label>';
        }

        if (validationMessages) {
          el.after(this.$compile('<div ng-show="' + baseFormName + '.' + inputName + '.$dirty">' + validationMessages + '</div>')(scope));
        }
      }
    }
});
```

It's pretty simple to use:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input show-errors data-se-required="Field required" 
           data-se-default="Field Invalid"
           name="myInput" ng-minlength="10" required />

</form>
```

The directive will automatically generate all of the html. It uses a div and labels, but can be adapted to use ngMessages if you want. JSFiddle is being a bit wonky at the moment. I'll try and add a working link tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

[ngMessageExp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessageExp) is what you are after.  This will show the 'other' error message when there is an error, but not the 'required' error.

```
<ng-messages for="myForm.number.$error">
  <ng-message when="required">Number is required</ng-message>
  <ng-message when-exp="['min', 'max']">There's something wrong with number!</ng-message>
</ng-messages>
```

You will have to add each error type to the list, but you should ***know*** what validations you are using.  In this case, only min and max.

If you find yourself repeating that generic catch all error message then consider using [ngMessageInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessagesInclude) that has the when-exp for all validation types that you use.

Comment: The real key here is "_but you should_ **know** _what validations you are using. In this case, only min and max._" Adding a default case is lazy (and admittedly what I was thinking about doing). You define each validator; be deliberate and define each message too. Use a hack like this if you want more than one to share the same thing.